# Unable to get values of selected elements in lwc js controller

Tags: javascript, lightning-experience, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I'm developing a Lightning Web Component, which has the add & delete row functionality. Each row contains 1 input text & 2 picklists. I want to capture the value of all the rows i.e input texts & picklist of each row when the user clicks on the submit button. But, I'm unable to get the entered/selected values in the js controller. 
Can anyone tell me the best way to capture the values for the dynamically added elements in the LWC?

**addDeleterow.html**

```
    <template>
    <template iterator:it={rows} >
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-horizontal_small" key={it.value.Id}>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                          {it.value.indexrow}       
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col" key={item}>    
                <lightning-combobox
                 value={value}
                 placeholder="Select Object Field"
                 options={populateFieldData}
                 class="slds-select-custom"
                 onchange={handleselectfield}>
                </lightning-combobox> 
            </div> 

            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-combobox 
                     name="salesforce object" 
                     value={value}
                     options={oprators} 
                     onchange={handleselectfield} 
                     class="slds-select-custom">
                </lightning-combobox>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input
                 type="TextArea"
                 value={it.value.Value}
                 class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"
                 onchange={handleselectfield}>

                 </lightning-input>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-icon variant="error" icon-name="utility:delete" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" onclick={delrow} size="small"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
        <div if:true={it.last} class="list-last"></div>               
        </div>    
    </template> 

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick={addrow}>
        <u>Add Criteria</u>
    </a>
</template>
```

**addDeleterow.js**

```
    /* eslint-disable getter-return */
/* eslint-disable no-unreachable */
/* eslint-disable no-irregular-whitespace */
/* eslint-disable eqeqeq */
/* eslint-disable guard-for-in */
/* eslint-disable no-debugger */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable vars-on-top */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

import { LightningElement ,track } from 'lwc';
import { getSFObjectFields } from "c/apexServices";
export default class AddDeleteRow extends LightningElement {
    @track rows = [];
    @track indexrow;
    @track fieldData;
    selectedfields = [];
    filterlogic = [];
    filtervalue = [];
    rowindex = 0;
    delrowindex;
    @track _selectedObject;
    @track trackRows = {};

    addrow(){

         this.rowindex = this.rowindex + 1;

        const obj = {
            "indexrow" : this.rowindex,
            "FieldName": '',
            "Operator": '',
            "Value": ''
        };
        this.rows.push(obj);

        console.log('====='+JSON.stringify(this.rows));
        console.log('====this.rows==='+this.rows); 
    }

    delrow(){

        const obj = {
            "indexrow" : 1,
            "FieldName": '',
            "Operator": '',
            "Value": ''
        };
        this.rows.pop(obj,this.rowindex);
        this.rowindex = this.rowindex - 1;
    }
    get oprators() {
        return [
            { label: 'Equals', value: 'equal' },
            { label: 'Does not equal', value: 'Doesnotequal' },
            { label: 'Starts with', value: 'Startswith' },
            { label: 'Ends with', value: 'Endswith' },
            { label: 'Contains', value: 'Contains' },
        ];
    }
    get populateFieldData(){
        return  [
            { label: 'Name', value: 'Name'},
            { label: 'Account Number', value: 'AccountNumber'},
            { label: 'Account Source', value: 'AccountSource'},
            { label: 'Annual Revenue', value: 'AnnualRevenue'},
            { label: 'Account Number', value: 'AccountNumber'},
            { label: 'Description', value: 'Description'},
            { label: 'Industry', value: 'Industry'},
            { label: 'Type', value: 'Type'},
            { label: 'Website', value: 'Website'}
        ];

    } 

    handleselectfield(event){
        this.selectedfields = event.target.value;
        console.log('====='+JSON.stringify(this.rows));
    }
    handlefilterlogic(event){
        this.filterlogic = event.target.value;
        console.log('*****filterlogic******'+ this.filterlogic);
    }
    handlefilterValue(event){
        this.filtervalue = event.target.value;
        console.log('*****filtervalue******'+ this.filtervalue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be [specific about your issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) here? As of now you only have lot of code here and its not very clear as what is your exact issue. If you can [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/258407/edit) to clearly mention what are you trying to achieve, what is the current behavior and issue you are facing, that will help anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one below things:

Add **index** in the data rows and add **data-index** attribute on the input components also add **name** attribute.

```
 <lightning-input
             type="TextArea"
             value={it.value.Value}
             class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"
             onchange={handleselectfield} data-index={it.index} name="first-name">
```

Now in **handleselectfield** method get the **index** value and update the row value like this:

```
handleselectfield(event){
   let currIndex = event.target.dataset.index;
   let fieldName = event.target.name;
   if( fieldName == 'first-name' ){
     this.rows[currIndex].firstName = event.target.value;
   }
   else if( fieldName == '<ANOTHER FIELD NAME>' ){
     this.rows[currIndex].<ANOTHER FIELD NAME> = event.target.value;
   }


   console.log('====='+JSON.stringify(this.rows));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vishnu, this is solution worked.